# Android Studio - How to prevent it from prompting for Proxy Settings?

Tags: android, windows, deployment, proxy

We work in a large college environment.  We are trying to get Android Studio v2.1.3 to work in large deployment for students doing our programming courses.  Once a student closes the application, it gets redeployed to the PC so we cannot just tick the box - we need to find out how to make the deployment not prompt for the proxy confirmation.  See the image for the prompt screen that we are seeing.

[Proxy prompt dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSqs3.png)
I assume it is something to enter into the gradle.properties file located into the user profile area - but I can't find the syntax that I would enter - if I have got the correct file!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using/creating the global gradle.properties file.
And adding the following configuration with your own values.

```
# Proxy settings
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my.proxy.host
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user name
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - but that's not the problem.  We just don't want the dialogue box to appear at all.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Well, I don't believe it is intended to show up if proxy settings are already configured, does it show up anyway?